# When is term-by-term differentiation/integration of Fourier series permissible?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Essentially what the title says. Note that I'm a novice in real analysis so bare with me. I'm told that these properties are allowed only is a series is uniformly convergent, but that's all I understand.
Are there any quick tests I can use to sow this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test
This is useful test for uniform convergence, but note that it will be inconclusive for series that are not absolutely convergent. So if a series fails the M-test, it may or may not be uniformly convergent.

Comment: This is an iconic question... If we are confined to talking about pointwise convergence, the answer is (as has been know for 200 years) complicated. If we allow ourselves to talk about distributions/generalized-functions, especially Sobolev spaces, things become... transparent. But what stage's answer do you want? Developmental stages are important, after all...

Comment: The main thing to know is that if $\sum_n |nc_n|^2<\infty$ then $\sum_n c_n 2i\pi n e^{2i\pi nx}$ converges in $L^2(\Bbb{R/Z})$ thus in $L^1(\Bbb{R/Z})$ thus we can integrate termwise to get that $\sum_n c_n e^{2i\pi nx}$ is its primitive whose Fourier series converges uniformly to a continuous function.